# Telegram bot php - Broadcasting location - how to read changes?

Tags: php, geolocation, bots, telegram

Tell me pls. How to read the broadcast, geo-location changes sent by the user to the bot?

**User -> Broadcasting location -> Telegram bot -> how to read changes?**

The code processes the sent message with the broadcast, but only the first sent data (longitude, latitude are of interest).

I'm using: **telegram-bot-sdk**

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$message = $this->update->getEditedMessage()

Help: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.editMessage